# Dynamic registry key in WSO2BRS

Tags: wso2, drools

Is it possible in WSO2BRS to have a registry key that is built up using data from the input fact?

My usecase: we have a hosted system for multiple customers, and for customer A I want to use rule file: conf:/rules/A/rules.drl, and for customer B I want to use rule file: conf:/rules/B/rules.drl.

That way we have rules in the registry so we can change them if necessary, and split them up over the customers.

Comment: From the Drools point of view, this would have to be done using two different sessions from two different rule bases. Or you'll have to use agenda groups. Don't know how this impacts WSO registry key.

Comment: From a drools point of view, there is a simpler way: the customer identifier is part of the incoming fact. So in the services file, it is possible to have multiple rule files / tables, each for a customer, with the first condition that the customer ID is correct. 

The disadvantage of this is, that when a new customer arrives, the service needs to be redeployed. And that I would like to prevent.

Comment: It appears that multiple dtable files in the service.rsl does not work: only the latest is picked up. So again I will need to dynamically load the file, or put all customers in one BIG sheet... that would not be nice.